# Class Not found exception while inflating a custom scroll view which is kept inside my Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Im keeping CustomScrollView inherited from HorizontalScrollView inside my MyActivity which extends FragmentActivity.While Running the App, it causes ClassNotFoundException - packagename.MyActivity.CustomScrollView not found!!...

How to solve this??

Thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You wanna refer to your custom scroll view as

```
<view class="packagename.MyActivity$CustomScrollView" />
```

Or possibly

```
<ViewGroup class="packagename.MyActivity$CustomScrollView" />
```

considering you're implementing a container. The reason it needs to be in a class attribute rather than the usual tag name style is that $ is needed to refer to nested classes, and $'s an illegal character in xml tag names.

Also note that MyActivity.CustomScrollView needs to be declared as public and static within MyActivity.

Answer (score 0):

not `packagename.MyActivity.CustomScrollView`

try

`packagename.MyActivity$CustomScrollView`

You said `CustomScrollView` is inside `MyActivity`, right?

I think you want this:

```
<com.tabs.MyActivity$CustomScrollView 
android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scrollbars="none" > 

</com.tabs.MyActivity$CustomScrollView>
```

notice the `$` instead of the `.`

Comment: I have given like this in xml file <com.tabs.MyActivity.CustomScrollView
         android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:scrollbars="none" >

         
     </com.tabs.MyActivity.CustomScrollView>